# How to remove duplicate/buffered frames from streamed video that has been saved locally?

Tags: video

I used [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) to download video streams but occasionally the output gets stuck and there are duplicate frames because of buffering.

Is there any way to go through the video and remove the stuck frames?

Comment: What format(s) are you working with? What have you tried so far and what research have you done?